# Extracting data from only the year

Tags: sql

I have data in a table in SQL with dates, but how do I select only those that happen in 2021. (The dates look like 31-oct-2020) in the table. The dates are the actual date variable, not just text.

Comment: What's your DBMS? What's the data type for that date column you've mentioned?

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: When making the table, I put "Stipdate date" for the variable if that helps. It's a "date" type variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should *avoid* storing your dates as text, but rather should use a proper date column.  That being said, you may check the right 4 characters of the date string:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE RIGHT(date_col, 4) = '2021';
```

If the column be an actual date type then use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE date_col >= '2021-01-01' AND date_col < '2022-01-01';
```

Comment: I'm sorry. It is a proper "date" variable. How do I do this with the proper date variable?

Comment: What is your database?

Comment: It's a table I created and enter in data myself.

Comment: SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE date_col >= '2021-01-01' AND date_col < '2022-01-01';                                       This worked perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If using MSSQL, you can leverage the `YEAR(...)` to extract the year from a date.

Replace  and , with the table name and date column name respectively.

`select * from <tablename> where year(<datecolumn>) = 2021`

Comment: I get "YEAR" is an invalid identifier.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your DB is Oracle after checking out your previous post. Then you can use

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM yourTable 
 WHERE EXTRACT(year FROM dt) = 2021
```

or

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM yourTable 
 WHERE TRUNC(dt,'YYYY') = date'2021-01-01'
```

or

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM yourTable 
 WHERE dt BETWEEN date'2021-01-01' AND date'2021-12-31'
```

You can benefit the index if there's one on the date column(namely `dt`) by using the last SELECT statement